# implode array strings two by two - php

Tags: php, implode

My array is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 4
    [7] => 7
)
```

I use this code:
implode( ",", $output );

but it returns this:
1,4,2,5,3,6,4,7,6

I want to 0 comes with 1 and 2 comes with 3 and etc with "ts" between them.
after both of them with "ts", it should come with a comma. like this :
1ts4,2ts5,3ts6,4ts7

summary: instead of odd commas (with the implode that I said), I want it to put "ts" (1ts4,2ts5,3ts6,4ts7)

Comment: U have use foreach loop also for above requirement

Comment: @RahulPawar Thank you but how to just change the odds? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:-

```
$arr = [1,4,2,5,3,6,4,7];
$strArr= [];
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i=$i+2){
  $strArr[] = "{$arr[$i]}ts{$arr[$i+1]}";
} 
echo implode(',',$strArr);
```

Edited

Answer (score 2):

You may use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) function to split an array into parts first and then implode them as you wish.

Comment: how to implode that? because it becomes two parts and I want to implode whether with comma and "ts"

Comment: Use foreach loop for chunked array to implode parts by "ts". Second step will be imploding result array with comma.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like below:-

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$arr = Array
(
    0 => 1,
    1 => 4,
    2 => 2,
    3 => 5,
    4 => 3,
    5 => 6,
    6 => 4,
    7 => 7
);

$new_array = array_chunk($arr,2); // break the array into sub-arrays of two-two values each

$my_string = ''; // an empty string
foreach ($new_array as $new_arra){ // iterate though the new chunked array

    $my_string .= implode('ts',$new_arra).','; // implode the sub-array and add to the variable
}

echo trim($my_string,','); // echo variable
```

Output:- 1ts4,2ts5,3ts6,4ts7

https://eval.in/686524

Answer (score 1):

I know I might be late in answering but this may be helpful without using `array_chunk` function and using single `for` loop like as

```
$arr = Array
(
    0 => 1,
    1 => 4,
    2 => 2,
    3 => 5,
    4 => 3,
    5 => 6,
    6 => 4,
    7 => 7
);

$res = [];
$count = count($arr);
for($k = 0; $k < $count; $k+=2)
{
    $res[] = isset($arr[$k+1]) ? "{$arr[$k]}ts{$arr[$k+1]}" : $arr[$k];
}

echo implode(",",$res);
```

**Output:**

```
1ts4,2ts5,3ts6,4ts7
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
<?php 
$a = Array(0 => 1,1 => 4,2 => 2,3 => 5,4 => 3,5 => 6,6 => 4,7 => 7);// your array
$i=1;
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    if ($i % 2 != 0) { 
        $newArr[] = $value."ts".$a[$i];
    }
    $i++;
}
print_r($newArr);
?>
```

Output:

> Array (
>       [0] => 1ts4
>       [1] => 2ts5
>       [2] => 3ts6
>       [3] => 4ts7 )

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
$array = [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 4,
    2 => 2,
    3 => 5,
    4 => 3,
    5 => 6,
    6 => 4,
    7 => 7,
];

$array = array_map( function( $item ) { return implode( 'ts', $item ); }, array_chunk( $array, 2 ) );
echo implode( ',', $array );
```